# Firewire devices do not show up in /dev

Tags: 14.04, drivers, udev, firewire

I am having trouble with my pci firewire card in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It previously worked fine but has been unused for a while and no longer works. The card shows up in lspci:

```
00:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6315 Series Firewire Controller (rev 01)
Subsystem: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6315 Series Firewire Controller
Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
```

However, I do not get fw0 and fw1 in /dev as before, so I cannot use the card. How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Try an older kernel if you still have one installed?

Comment: @user.dz I already tried that, but it didn't help.

Comment: Firewire support has changed in the recent past.  My system used to use ffado and now uses a derivative in alsa, of which I think firewire_ohci is a part.  I've been trying to find out how to swap back to ffado to check or verify some odd behaviour on my external device.  Sadly I'm still trying to find it.